# Threadsafe 'get' from form slider (TrackBar)

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety, trackbar

I have an application with an initial form that has various configurations (checkboxes, text boxes, sliders/trackbars).  When I initiate the action that uses those configurations, there's a worker process that's called:

```
private void btnx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  bgWorkerX.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bgWorkerX_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dictCfgOut = GenerateConfigDict();
    XGen.CreateX.aReadFile(inputPathXRAW.Text,  outputPathX.Text, dictCfgOut);
}
```

The GenerateConfigDict function creates a `Dictionary<string, object>` of config data. This is because the data needed varies (a few bools, some ints, an array of strings).  The code where this is created is below:

```
    private Dictionary<string, object> GenerateConfigDict()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> ConfigDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        if (cbXAddOnus.Checked)
        {
            if (!MiscTools.ValidateX(txtInstX.Text, true))
                return null;
        }

        ConfigDict.Add("Available Images", GenerateConfigImageArray());
        ConfigDict.Add("X SCSC Hot", (cbXAddSCSC.Checked) ? (bool)true : (bool)false);
        ConfigDict.Add("X Req Adj", (cbXAddAdjustment.Checked) ? (bool)true : (bool)false);
        ConfigDict.Add("X Items", (cbXAddX.Checked) ? (bool)true : (bool)false);
        ConfigDict.Add("X Use Something", (cbXAddX.Checked) ? (bool)true : (bool)false);
        ConfigDict.Add("X Somedata", (string)txtX.Text);
        ConfigDict.Add("X Use SAN", (cbX.Checked) ? (bool)true : (bool)false);
        ConfigDict.Add("X % Y", (int)sliderX.Value);

        return ConfigDict;
    }
```

The sliderX.Value part was just added today.  Prior to this everything worked great.  However, with only that bit, I get:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'sliderX' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.

First, why is reading that value not threadsafe, but reading checkboxes and text is?  Second, I've poked around regarding making that threadsafe, but it all seems to require another function to call that value asynchronously.  I've already taken measures to ensure that the slider is disabled while the worker is running, so changes cannot be made from the form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access any control thread-safely you should call Invoke() method of that control ([MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)).

So, you piece of code will look like this:

```
delegate int GetSliderValueCallback();

private int GetValue()
{
    int sliderValue;
    if (sliderX.InvokeRequired)
    {
        GetSliderValueCallback cb = new GetSliderValueCallback(GetValue);
        return (int)sliderX.Invoke(cb);
    }
    else
    {
        return (int)sliderX.Value;
    }
}
```

And call it when reading values:

```
ConfigDict.Add("X % Y", GetValue());
```

I also would recommend you to use [async methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

```
private async void btnx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await bgWorkerX_DoWorkAsync();
}

private async void bgWorkerX_DoWorkAsync()
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dictCfgOut = await GenerateConfigDictAsync();
    XGen.CreateX.aReadFile(inputPathXRAW.Text,  outputPathX.Text, dictCfgOut);
}

private Task<Dictionary<string, object>> GenerateConfigDictAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => {
        Dictionary<string, object> ConfigDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        if (cbXAddOnus.Checked)
        {
            if (!MiscTools.ValidateX(txtInstX.Text, true))
                return null;
        }

        ConfigDict.Add("Available Images", GenerateConfigImageArray());
        ConfigDict.Add("X SCSC Hot", (cbXAddSCSC.Checked) ? (bool)true : (bool)false);
        ConfigDict.Add("X Req Adj", (cbXAddAdjustment.Checked) ? (bool)true : (bool)false);
        ConfigDict.Add("X Items", (cbXAddX.Checked) ? (bool)true : (bool)false);
        ConfigDict.Add("X Use Something", (cbXAddX.Checked) ? (bool)true : (bool)false);
        ConfigDict.Add("X Somedata", (string)txtX.Text);
        ConfigDict.Add("X Use SAN", (cbX.Checked) ? (bool)true : (bool)false);
        ConfigDict.Add("X % Y", (int)sliderX.Value);

        return ConfigDict;
    });
}
```

**WARNING!** Unfortunately I do not have chance to build that code (I've wrote it just here), so, please use it **just as example**.

Comment: Would it be possible to call GetValue() with an object GetValue(object obj) so that the one call can get values from different controls?  The whole point of building the dict to begin with was to push all of the config data, but the further back I have to start pushing from, the more I'm just shoving the data along from place to place.

Comment: Of course, return type of Invoke() is Object (that is why I explicitly casted it to int). But parameter type must be Control or you should safely cast to it: var control = obj as Control; if (control == null) return null;

Comment: what would be the benefit of running the workers asynchronously?  While the worker is busy, the user should not be able to do anything with the application except wait (which they are informed of), and the workers themselves step through an iterative process, as many as 1000 times, that must be done in strict order.

Comment: @JesseWilliams, please read article on MSDN that I had provided before in the answer. In a nutshell: 1) it takes care about marshaling to UI thread when it is required automatically; 2) speed of parallel computing (of course, if you need it); 3) exception handling. In your case you can show some progress bar to user if your operation takes time (for example, reading file) and disable button "btnx". Anyway, it is up to you ;)

Answer (score 1):

The threading behavior of controls has to do with unmanaged code being wrapped by .NET. I don't know exactly which property *can* and/or *should* be accessed from any thread and why.

I wouldn't use the `Invoke` call back to the UI thread unless you need "real time" access to controls (ie. to update a `ProgressBar` value). Instead, before running the background worker, gather the UI stuff on the UI thread and supply them to the worker:

```
bgWorkerX.RunWorkerAsync((int)sliderX.Value);
...
private void bgWorkerX_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dictCfgOut = GenerateConfigDict((int)e.Argument);
    ...
}

private Dictionary<string, object> GenerateConfigDict(int sliderValue)
{
    ...
    ConfigDict.Add("X % Y", sliderValue);
    ...
}
```

Instead of just this value, you could even choose to create the whole config dictionary on the UI thread, and then use that as the agrument for the background worker.